# Obtaining decimal format for range of years and specific months

Tags: python, numpy, date, datetime, jupyter

I have monthly data (1993 - 2019) but I am hoping to get the decimal format of only July, August, and September months from 1993 - 2019.

Below is the code for the months in decimal format between 1993 - 2019 (all 12 months) but hoping to get the same thing but just for July, August, and September months:

```
year_start = 1993
year_end = 2019

full_time_months = np.arange(year_start+.5/12,year_end+1,1/12)

print(full_time_months[:12])

# these are the 12 months in 1993 as decimals

1993.04166667 1993.125      1993.20833333 1993.29166667 1993.375
 1993.45833333 1993.54166667 1993.625      1993.70833333 1993.79166667
 1993.875      1993.95833333
```

My goal is to just get an array of months july, august, and september:

1993.54167, 1993.625, 1993.708... 2019.54167 , 2019.625, 2019.708

where year.54167 = July, year.625 = August, and year.708 = September.

How might I go about doing this? Hope my question is clear enough, please comment if something is unclear, thank you!!!

Comment: Why? Use DateTime objects - not floats ....

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm having issues with changing the xticks when plotting and using datetime objects, but with numpy floats there aren't issues with xticks, plotting etc :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with this, but you can do something like this, to separate the data you want.

```
import numpy as np

year_start = 1993
year_end = 2019


full_time_months = np.arange(year_start+.5/12,year_end+1,1/12)
# Reshape into 2D array
full_time_months = full_time_months.reshape(-1, 12)

# Choose selected columns
# July, Aug, Sept
selected_months = full_time_months[:, [6,7,8]]
print(selected_months)
```

Results:

```
[[1993.54166667 1993.625      1993.70833333]
 [1994.54166667 1994.625      1994.70833333]
...
 [2018.54166667 2018.625      2018.70833333]
 [2019.54166667 2019.625      2019.70833333]]
```